# In Tornado, how can I see Exceptions rasied in a coroutine called by PeriodicCallback?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I wrote a program which has a coroutine called periodically from the main `ioloop` like this:

```
from tornado import ioloop, web, gen, log
tornado.log.enable_pretty_printing()
import logging; logging.basicConfig()

@gen.coroutine
def callback():
    print 'get ready for an error...'
    raise Exception()
    result = yield gen.Task(my_async_func)

l = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
cb = ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback, 1000, io_loop=l)
cb.start
l.start()
```

The output I get is simply:

```
$ python2 app.py
get ready for an error...
get ready for an error...
get ready for an error...
get ready for an error...
```

The `raise Exception()` is silently ignored! If I change the callback to be just

```
def callback():
    print 'get ready for an error...'
    raise Exception()
```

I get a full stack trace like I expect (and need). How can I get that stack trace while using the coroutine?

Answer (score 7):

`@tornado.gen.coroutine` makes function return `tornado.concurrent.Future` object so you don't have to wrap it into `tornado.gen.Task` but you can call it using `yield` keyword:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def inner():
    logging.info('inner')

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def outer():
    logging.info('outer')
    yield inner()
```

An exception in function decorated this way is wrapped into this `tornado.concurrent.Future` object and it can be returned later using its `exception()` method. In your case `tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback` calls your callback method and after that it's just throwing away returned `tornado.concurrent.Future` object along with exception it contained. To detect exception you can use chain calling:

```
@tornado.gen.coroutine
def inner():
    raise Exception()

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def outer():
    try:
        yield inner()   
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)
```

But in your case it's actually easier just to catch it just after throwing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tornado.gen
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options
import logging

tornado.options.parse_command_line()

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def callback():
    logging.info('get ready for an error...')
    try:
        raise Exception()   
    except Exception, e:
        logging.exception(e)

main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
scheduler = tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback(callback, 1000, io_loop = main_loop)
scheduler.start()
main_loop.start()
```

`@gen.engine` does not make function return a `tornado.concurrent.Future` so exceptions aren't wrapped.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand exactly why, but changing `@gen.coroutine` to `@gen.engine` allows the exception to bubble up properly. It still works asynchronously too.

Comment: To handle exceptions gen.coroutine catches "Exception" errors. gen.engine do not do that.
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23502625/1066801