# Difference in tornado.gen.engine v/s tornado.gen.coroutine

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

Going by the tornado.gen [documentation](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/gen.html) can someone help me understand the exact difference between tornado.gen.coroutine and tornado.gen.engine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the tornado documentation for `gen.engine` says:

> This decorator is similar to coroutine, except it does not return a
>   Future and the callback argument is not treated specially.

And as the `gen.coroutine` documentation says

> From the caller’s perspective, @gen.coroutine is similar to the
>   combination of @return_future and @gen.engine.

`gen.engine` is basically an older, less streamlined version of what coroutine does. If you're writing new code, you should follow the documentation's advice and always use `tornado.gen.coroutine`.

It's pretty evident if you look at the code for both functions (with documentation stripped out).

engine:

```
def engine(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        runner = None

        def handle_exception(typ, value, tb):
            if runner is not None:
                return runner.handle_exception(typ, value, tb)
            return False
        with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exception) as deactivate:
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except (Return, StopIteration) as e:
                result = getattr(e, 'value', None)
            else:
                if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
                    def final_callback(value):
                        if value is not None:
                            raise ReturnValueIgnoredError(
                                "@gen.engine functions cannot return values: "
                                "%r" % (value,))
                        assert value is None
                        deactivate()
                    runner = Runner(result, final_callback)
                    runner.run()
                    return
            if result is not None:
                raise ReturnValueIgnoredError(
                    "@gen.engine functions cannot return values: %r" %
                    (result,))
            deactivate()
            # no yield, so we're done
    return wrapper
```

coroutine:

```
def coroutine(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        runner = None
        future = TracebackFuture()

        if 'callback' in kwargs:
            callback = kwargs.pop('callback')
            IOLoop.current().add_future(
                future, lambda future: callback(future.result()))

        def handle_exception(typ, value, tb):
            try:
                if runner is not None and runner.handle_exception(typ, value, tb):
                    return True
            except Exception:
                typ, value, tb = sys.exc_info()
            future.set_exc_info((typ, value, tb))
            return True
        with ExceptionStackContext(handle_exception) as deactivate:
            try:
                result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except (Return, StopIteration) as e:
                result = getattr(e, 'value', None)
            except Exception:
                deactivate()
                future.set_exc_info(sys.exc_info())
                return future
            else:
                if isinstance(result, types.GeneratorType):
                    def final_callback(value):
                        deactivate()
                        future.set_result(value)
                    runner = Runner(result, final_callback)
                    runner.run()
                    return future
            deactivate()
            future.set_result(result)
        return future
    return wrapper
```

Both of these are probably pretty hard to understand at first glance. But still, it's obvious that the code is very similar, except that `@gen.coroutine` has some special handling of the `callback` kwarg, and it builds/returns a `Future`. `@gen.engine` has some code that specifically throws an error if you try to return something from it, rather than putting it in the `Future`.