# Best way to do Asynchronous Process handling in Tornado,python?

Tags: rest, python-2.7, tornado, asynchronous

Please help me out.. My confusion is mostly on the difference between tornado.gen.engine and tornado.gen.coroutine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference in tornado.gen.engine v/s tornado.gen.coroutine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23502338/difference-in-tornado-gen-engine-v-s-tornado-gen-coroutine)

Comment: But if you want some basic examples of code with Tornado coroutines, I have a blog post: http://emptysqua.re/blog/refactoring-tornado-coroutines/

Comment: I have gone through that post. But it didn't satisfy my criteria. It will be my pleasure if someone help me to give some links of basic example of asynchronous networking of Tornado. Thank you in advance.